# How are jinja values returned in this context?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, return-value

I am new to learning jinja/flask and have a relatively low comprehension thus far. If someone could help with this, that would be great. I am having some trouble understanding how to access the values of the variable here. I made a feeble attempt with no success. I get errors when I click my "submit" button to try to get my name to print on the next page after "Welcome, ".

Alright, I have an index page with a form and I would like to return the submitted value on the POST page as shown below. However, I am having trouble with the syntax. This is built in Pycharm with Flask using python/jinja2/html. That is where some of my confusion exists I believe.

EDIT_1: I understand this topic has several previous postings, but I cannot seem to apply what those posts explain. Actually, the very code I have in here is from another post I found on here.

Here is the Python File:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/username", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def username():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       user = request.form
        return render_template("username.html", username=user)
    return print("Something went wrong...smash your computer!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the Index file that contains the form in which I would like to obtain the username:

```
...
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="title_head">
    <p class="title"> Gauntlet  </p>
    </div>
    <div id="working_area">
    <form action = "http://localhost:5000/username" method = "POST">
        <p>Enter Username: <input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
        <p><input type = "submit" value = "SUBMIT" /></p>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, here is the username POST page (I will include the relevant part here):

```
...
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="title_head">
        <p class="title"> Gauntlet  </p>
    </div>
    <div id="working_area">
        {% for user in username %}
        <p>Welcome, {{ username.user }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `user=request.form` to `username=request.form["Name"]`.

And then, change `return render_template("username.html", username=user)` to `render_template("username.html", username=username)`.

Last, modify the template file of `username.html`:

```
...
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="title_head">
            <p class="title"> Gauntlet  </p>
        </div>
        <div id="working_area">
            <p>Welcome, {{ username }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: On the other templating engine I could use username.user but that is not the part of the problem here obviously.

Comment: do I need to change the assignment in the .py file? 
  `  user = request.form["Name"]`

to 

   ` username = request.form["Name"]?`

EDIT: Answered my own question. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the code(flask) you use to parse the form data with. You need to supply the `key` of the form element in which you are entering the data.

Add `user=request.form['Name']` to the code and you will have the required value in the variable username.Then you can do something like :

```
return render_template("username.html", username=user)
```

Comment: @stamaimer Ok . I get that. I am not too familiar with the jinja templating engine. OP can improve the template though.